# How to not serialize @Id field in Spring Boot @RestController?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity class with a Long id field. As a default, this field gets serialized to response with a Spring Boot rest controller.

I am using Spring Data JPA

I donot want to serialize this field into my response. I tried using @Transient, but that won't work. I can create a DTO object, but just wanted to check if there is a better way of achieving this behaviour?

Comment: Try @JsonIgnore

Comment: Do not use entities in controller

Comment: `@JsonView` can be used. More info here https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should avoid returning entities in controller responses. It is not suitable for projection needs, create coupling between your access layer with the view one and potential side effect like lazy loading caused by some anti patterns like `open session in view`.
But... if it still ok to you just add `@jsonIgnore` on the `id` field.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Enity in your response.
Use another DTO class with fields you want to use. And map all data from entity to DTO class.